# How to find modal value accross List<List<double>> for each inner value?

Tags: c#, linq, list, modal-dialog

This is remarkably similar to another question I asked previously. I have no idea how to do things in Linq so I need some help with this one. I want to find the Modal value of a List> for each inner value.

I have the following list:

```
    List<List<double>> myFullList = new List<List<double>>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfLoops; i++)
    { 
       List<double> myInnerList = new List<double>();

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
           // Populate inner list with random numbers
           myInnerList.Add(double myRandomNumber);
        }

    // Add the inner list to the full list
    myFullList.Add(myInnerList);
   }
```

The list should look something like this:

```
myFullList[0] = {rand#1,rand#2,rand#3,...,rand#10}
myFulllist[1] = {rand#1,rand#2,rand#3,...,rand#10}
.
.
.
.
myFulllist[1] = {rand#1,rand#2,rand#3,...,rand#10}
```

I need to find the MODAL VALUE for that data to form ONE single list that looks something like this:

```
List<double> mode= new List<double>();
mode= {mode#1, mode#2........mode#10}
```

This output variable will find the mode of the data for the same "row" of data in the inner list.

Simple example:

```
innerList[0] = {1.00,2.00,3.00};
innerList[1] = {3.00,2.00,8.00};    
innerList[2] = {3.00,9.00,1.00};
innerList[3] = {3.00,1.00,1};

fullList = {innerList[0], innerList[1], innerList[2], innerList[3]};

modeList = {3,2,1};
```

Comment: You are always adding the same list. I'm missing  `myInnerList = new List<double>()` at the beggining of the inner loop.

Comment: I fixed that portion of the code by creating a new list each time the program loops. Sorry for the confusion. The bit I need help with might be clearer from the "simple example" portion of my question. I already have the lists, I just need to figure out how to get the modal value across the inner lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but probably easier to Understand. It has been succesfully tested :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int numberOfLoops = 10;

        List<List<int>> myFullList = new List<List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++)
        {
            List<int> myInnerList = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                // Populate inner list with random numbers
                myInnerList.Add(rnd.Next(0, 10));
            }

            // Add the inner list to the full list
            myFullList.Add(myInnerList);
        }


        myFullList = Transpose<int>(myFullList);

        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        foreach (List<int> subList in myFullList)
            result.Add(Mode(subList));

        //TO-DO: linq version!
        //List<int> result = myFullList.ForEach(num => Mode(num));

    }

    public static int Mode(List<int> x)
    {
        int mode = x.GroupBy(v => v)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .First()
            .Key;

        return mode;
    }

    public static List<List<T>> Transpose<T>(List<List<T>> lists)
    {
        var longest = lists.Any() ? lists.Max(l => l.Count) : 0;
        List<List<T>> outer = new List<List<T>>(longest);
        for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++)
            outer.Add(new List<T>(lists.Count));
        for (int j = 0; j < lists.Count; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++)
                outer[i].Add(lists[j].Count > i ? lists[j][i] : default(T));
        return outer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Pep, thank you, it looks like your transpose function is just the ticket that I needed. Once the lists are transposed, finding the mode is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

That's quiet simple, here is code (sorry, haven't fully tested it, but it's good to start with):

```
public static class ModalHelper
    {
        public static List<double> GetModals(List<List<double>> source)
        {
            return source.Select(list => list.Sum()/list.Count).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I'll give this a try and see if it does the job. Like I said I am very "noob" when it comes to Linq. I'll let you know if it worked in a bit.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that will be giving me the Modal value for my list. The mode is the most repeating value. Wouldnt "list.Sum() / list.Count()" just give me the average?   I can already do that with: "averageList = myFullList[0].Select((v, c) =>myFullList.Average(r => r[c])).ToList();"

Comment: Yep, just tried it and it only gives me the average, I need the modal value. I also need it to be the modal value across the rows of each inner list.

Comment: @JohnAugust, Sorry, i misunderstood your question. What do you mean when you say "Modal"? I've read your example and still don't understand :(

Comment: @JohnAugust, do you need to form a list of values, which have most occurances in inner lists? (let's say, matrix)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give the mode:

```
var temp = myFullList.SelectMany(l => l).GroupBy(all => all).Select(result => new
{
    Value = result.Key,
    Count = result.Count()
}).OrderByDescending(t => t.Count);
```

Explanation:
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - The `SelectMany`

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence.

So it gives us each decimal from the sub lists. We then group that by the decimals themselves and select the count for each along with their value. Finally we order by the count to give the most frequently occurring decimals first.

**Edit based on the comment from Robert S**

It seems the above code isn't what was required. As Robert S points out that code gives the mode of ALL numbers in the `List<List<double>>` but the question is how to get the mode from each *column*.

The following code should give the mode per column. Note that this code ignores duplicates; if more than one number appears the same amount of times the first number will be given:

```
var result1 = myFullList[0].Select((l, i) => new
{
    Column = i,
    Mode = myFullList.GroupBy(fl => fl[i]).OrderByDescending(t => t.Count()).Select(t => t.Key).FirstOrDefault()
});

foreach (var item in result1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", item.Column, item.Mode));
}
```

The code is using the overload of `Select` to take the index of the element (the column in the OP's definition). It then groups each item at that index. Note there are no bounds checks on `myFullList` but in production code there should be.

If duplicates are an issue we need two steps:

```
var temp2 = myFullList[0].Select((l, i) => new
{
    Column = i,
    Mode = myFullList.GroupBy(fl => fl[i]).Select(t => new { Number = t.Key, Count = t.Count() }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Count)
});

var result2 = temp2.Select(t => new
{
    Column = t.Column,
    Mode = t.Mode.Where(m => m.Count == t.Mode.Max(tm => tm.Count))
});

foreach (var item in result2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Mode.Count(); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", item.Column, item.Mode.ElementAt(i)));
    }
}
```

In the above code `temp2.Mode` will contain an IEnumerable of an anonymous object containing the number and how many times that number has appeared. `result2` is then populated by grabbing each of those items where the count matches the max of the count.

Given the input:

```
myFullList.Add(new List<double> { 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 });
myFullList.Add(new List<double> { 3.00, 2.00, 3.00 });
myFullList.Add(new List<double> { 3.00, 9.00, 1.00 });
myFullList.Add(new List<double> { 3.00, 1.00, 1 });
```

The first code outputs

```
0 3
1 2
2 3
```

and the second outputs

```
0 3
1 2
2 3
2 1
```

Note we have two outputs for column 2 as both 3 and 1 are equally popular.

Comment: This gives me the error: "The type or namespace all could not be found, are you missing a namespace or directive?"

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my first code snippet - have you seen my edit?

Comment: This will return a list of all values sorted by their occurence in all lists. But the OP wants the modal value per column if I understand him right.

Answer (score 0):

This linq query should do the trick

```
var result = list.Select<List<double>, List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>>(sub =>
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> elems = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>(sub.Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < sub.Count; ++i)
        elems.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(i, sub[i]));

    return elems;
}).SelectMany((x) => x).GroupBy((x) => x.Key).Select<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<int, double>>, double>(x =>
{
    var y = x.GroupBy(g => g.Value).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
    return y.First().First().Value;
});
```

Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<double>> list = new List<List<double>>();
    list.Add(new List<double> { 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 });
    list.Add(new List<double> { 3.00, 2.00, 8.00 });
    list.Add(new List<double> { 3.00, 9.00, 1.00 });
    list.Add(new List<double> { 3.00, 1.00, 1 });

    var result = list.Select<List<double>, List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>>(sub =>
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, double>> elems = new List<KeyValuePair<int, double>>(sub.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < sub.Count; ++i)
            elems.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, double>(i, sub[i]));

        return elems;
    }).SelectMany((x) => x).GroupBy((x) => x.Key).Select<IGrouping<int, KeyValuePair<int, double>>, double>(x =>
    {
        var y = x.GroupBy(g => g.Value).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
        return y.First().First().Value;
    });

    foreach (double val in result)
        Console.Write(val + " ");

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Here a live version at ideone: http://ideone.com/ye2EhG

First the lists are transformed to lists of key-value-pairs which add the information of the index inside each list. Then these lists are flattened to one single list and then this new list is grouped by the index. The groups are ordered by the count of values and the most-frequent element is returned for each group.